# Как привязать график к системе координат canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

Как привязать систему координат, без отрицательных значений от 0, по y - были секунды, по x - коэффициенты и если например стрелка выходит за границы, то добавлять на систему координат значения как здесь https://www.wink.org/?r=cryptofriend#/platform/dice-moon

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('crash-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

requestAnimationFrame(animate)

function lerp(a,b,t) {
  return a + (b-a)*t
}

function animate(t){
  t /= 2000;
  if (t > 1) return;
  let x = lerp(10, 590, t)
  let y = lerp(390, 100, t)
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  arrow({x: 10, y: 390}, {x, y}, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

function arrow (p1, p2, size) {
  var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y) , (p2.x - p1.x));
  var hyp = Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  
  // line
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#01f593';
  ctx.lineWidth = "5";
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, 0);
  ctx.stroke();

  // triangle
  ctx.fillStyle = '#01f593';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size , size/2);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, -size/2);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();

  ctx.fillStyle = '#01f59344';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(0,390);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x,390);
  ctx.fill();


}
```

```css
body {
  background:black
}
```

```html
<canvas width="999" height="400" id="crash-canvas" style="width: 999px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: а зачем Вы удалили прошлый вопрос, а в этот скопировали код из моего ответа?

Comment: так будет понятнее просто

Comment: stackowerflow не для этого, это база вопросов и ответов, я потратил время как на вопрос, так и на ответ, а вы его удалили,  почитайте правила https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: прошу прощение, не ознакомился, очень сильно извиняюсь

Comment: может кто помочь с этим?