# Не срабатывает вызов функции JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

есть код, после завершения таймера должна срабатывать requestAnimationFrame(animate) - отрисовка canvas, но она не срабатывает

```
//Таймер обратного отсчета
    let waitTimeShow = $('#waitTimeShow');
    let mutShow = $('#mutShow');

    let timerTime = 5;
    waitTimeShow.html(timerTime + "s");
    function timer(){
        timerTime--;
        waitTimeShow.html(timerTime + "s");
        if (timerTime == 0){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            waitTimeShow.addClass('hide');
            mutShow.removeClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function(){},1000);
        } else {
            setTimeout(timer,1000);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(timer,1000);  

     function lerp(a,b,t) {
      return a + (b-a)*t 
    }

    function animate(t){
      t /= 2000; // Время анимации
      if (t > 1) return;
      let x = lerp(10, 590, t)
      let y = lerp(390, 100, t)
      ctx.clearRect(40, 40, canvas.width, canvas.height - 70);
      arrow({x: 40, y: canvas.height - 40}, {x, y}, 40);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

    function arrow (p1, p2, size) {
      var angle = Math.atan2((p2.y - p1.y) , (p2.x - p1.x));
      var hyp = Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));

      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(p1.x, p1.y);
      ctx.rotate(angle);

      // line
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#e4c358';
      ctx.lineWidth = "8";
      ctx.beginPath();  
      ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, 0);
      ctx.stroke();

      // triangle
      ctx.fillStyle = '#e4c358';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(hyp - size , size/2);
      ctx.lineTo(hyp, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(hyp - size, -size/2);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.restore();

      ctx.fillStyle = '#e4c358ab';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(40,canvas.height - 40);
      ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p2.x,canvas.height - 40);
      ctx.fill();
    }
```

Comment: непонятно, что за объект ctx. нигде не объявлен. requestAnimationFrame, который вызывается через 5 секунд, тоже не объявлен. также рекомендую использовать console.log, таймер вроде правильно написан, но мало ли какая ошибка в логах.

Comment: в логах нет ошибок

Comment: в начало requestAnimationFrame вставьте console.log('requestAnimationFrame'). так вы точно будете уверены, что проблемы с таймером нет. а проблема, скажем в canvas.

Comment: если в таймере вставлю так requestAnimationFrame(animate(2000)), то график появляется без анимации и в консоле ругается, что лишний аргумент 2000

Comment: ну наверное потому, что requestAnimationFrame принимает на вход функцию, а не ее значение. 2000 нужно передавать отдельным аргументом (если он предусмотрен). а вобще трудно что-то сказать, не видя полный код (нет requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: вот я набросал пример рабочий этого кода https://codepen.io/maxim-drozdow/pen/rNNJXej

Comment: таймер это муть, все должно быть засинхронизировано на одно и то же время, просто сначала должна быть  анимация обратного отсчета, а потом анимация графика, задержку можно было дабавить однос йтрочкой, после `t /= 2000`

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, при вызовые функции `animate` переменная t у вас всегда больше 1, поэтому происходит выход из функции. Во-вторых, в предоставленом фрагменте кода отсутствует определение ctx, поэтому даже если убрать строчку `if (t > 1) return;`, то получаем `ReferenceError: ctx is not defined`.

Comment: а как решить проблему с t ?

Comment: наверное эта строчка имеет смысл, раз ее написали ) вобще интересно приведенный выше код когда-нибудь работал?

Comment: @Corona а за что отвечает t?

Comment: я вот и пишу его) смысл такой, по истечению таймера, запустить построение диаграммы привязанной к системе координат, пока это тестово, но вообще нужно по оси y сделать секунду, по оси X коэффициенты как здесь https://www.wink.org/?r=cryptofriend#/platform/dice-moon

Comment: t - для анимации прорисовки графика, чтобы не сразу показывался

Comment: @АлексейОбухов это фрагмент из моего ответа, на вопрос, который автор удалил, и да, он работал =) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1042742/188366